# Several applications give "libtasn1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: shared-library

I get this error when I try running LibreOffice after upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04.

```
~$> libreoffice --writer

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libtasn1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This problem relate to more programs than just libreoffice.

```
 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libtasn1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Output of strace

```
~$> strace filezilla
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libtasn1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffc19f9310) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libtasn1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fffc19f9310) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libtasn1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fffc19f9310) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
...
writev(2, [{"filezilla", 9}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libtasn1.so.3", 13}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libtasn1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) = 122
exit_group(127)
```

Comment: This problem relate to more programs than just libreoffice. /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libtasn1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: temporary solution for me was to copy the libtasn1.so.3 from my Steam installation folder. I'm guessing this problem is not with the programs (Flashplayer, Libreoffice, Chromium, Empathy SSL, Filezilla), but with a library... Maybe I need to fore re-installation of a library after my upgrade to 14.04?

Comment: updated the question with a strace example. The same output is valid for LibreOffice. Error in Empathy and Flashplayer happens in runtime, and do only break https:// functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Remove file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/testlib.conf`.

This problem was caused by me testing some Gnome developement last year.

The developement-enviroment had set up a `/opt/testlib/` folder, with an old version of `libgnutls26`. The `/opt/testlib/` folder was pointed to in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/testlib.conf`.

I found the problem after analyzing all open(...)-calls in the `strace`-log.

Helping strace-log:

```
~$> strace filezilla
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/opt/testlib/lib/libgnutls.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
```

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Next time be sure to clean your dev environment after you end. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The libtasn1.3 library was [replaced with libtasn1.6 as of the Trusty (14.04) release](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libtasn1-3/+bug/1303878). For some reason you don't have the new library installed/used. Verify that you have it installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install libtasn1-6
```

If that doesn't work, upgrade your package too:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-upgrade
```

Comment: Yes, is installed. I don't know why my software is looking for 1.3.

Comment: @landas did you tried removing the programs? Try `aptitude why libreoffice libtasn1-6` and add the results to your error.

Comment: I did try to reinstall the programs, with no luck. I have now found the answer. Thank you very much for trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix this by installing libtasn1-3.  This is a transitional package in Trusty, and you can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtasn1-3-bin
```

Comment: Yes, it is installed. I even tried to completly reinstall it, but it has no effect on the error message. It does not install the libtasn1.so.3 library file.